# How can I debug a CorelDRAW X6 add-in using Visual Studio Pro 2013

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2013, com, add-in, coreldraw

Every time I choose *Debug.. Attach To Process* and choose `CorelDRW.exe`, it crashes `CorelDRAW`, and Visual Studio reports:

```
The program '[1028] CorelDRW.exe' has exited with code -1073741819 (0xc0000005) 'Access violation'.
```

Answer (score 0):

CorelDRAW X6 blocks debuggers from attaching to the process.

You may have more luck with X7.